# Meteor schemas autoform hooks has inconsistent values

Tags: meteor, schema, hook

I have two update forms, one for each of two collections, which have identical before update hooks.

```
before:{
  update: function(docId, modifier, template){
    console.log(arguments);
    return modifier;
  }
}
```

One gives me:

```
["eEWR4xqdZjdprKGN7", Object, Blaze.TemplateInstance]
```

Which is exactly what I expect and all is great.

The other gives me:

```
[Object, Blaze.TemplateInstance]
```

`Object` here has `$set` and `$unset` keys with corresponding `Object`s giving me the values I expect to see that I put in my form.

Beyond that... I'm using autosave with both forms. I'm not sure what other information to post. I have a LOT of code and pretty beefy schemas, and I don't know what would cause this or where to start.

The problem it's giving me is that I have a helper function registered to update the forms on their respective templates using Meteor's awesome reactive stuff, which isn't happening on the second form. But it works on the first.

```
Template.updatePerson.helpers({
  getDocument: function(){
    return people.find(this.person_id).fetch()[0];
  }
});
```

Again, these two forms are nearly identical except for the schemas and names, but I've tried lots of adjusting to the second schema with no change.

Anyone who can tell me why those two arguments coming back are different would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ends up my helper on the second template wasn't properly pulling the document ID (looking for wrong key). The results I was seeing must have been from autoform not having access to a document for its update method.